# Android programming passing values

Tags: android

Sorry if we're doing anything wrong, we just started a crash course in android and we are trying to pass a value using the bundle but it does not show any error, it only crashes after the attempt. Here is the code block below.
ps, pls feel free to edit the post if you see anything wrong with it.

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle(); //to pass values in meals.java
    b.putStringArray("breakfast1" , new String[]{breakfast1[0]});
    Intent gene = new Intent(Calories.this, Days.class);
    //to pass the activity in another activity

    gene.putExtras(gene);
    startActivity(gene);


    //second.java bundle receiving code block
    break1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.break1);
    Intent gene = getIntent();
    String[] break2 = gene.getStringArrayExtra("breakfast1");

    break1.setText(break2[0]);
```

Comment: change `gene.putExtras(gene);` to `gene.putExtras(b);`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `gene.putExtras(gene);` to `gene.putExtras(b);` and retrieve bundle using `b = getIntent().getExtras()`

**FirstActivity**

```
Bundle b = new Bundle(); //to pass values in meals.java
b.putStringArray("breakfast1" , new String[]{breakfast1[0]});
Intent gene = new Intent(Calories.this, Days.class);
//to pass the activity in another activity

gene.putExtras(b); //put bundle to intent
startActivity(gene);
```

In Second Activity **Second.java**

```
break1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.break1);
Intent gene = getIntent();
Bundle b = gene.getExtras(); //get bundle from intent
String[] break2 = b.getStringArrayExtra("breakfast1"); //get array list from bundle

break1.setText(break2[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace with this.

```
 Bundle b = new Bundle(); //to pass values in meals.java
    b.putStringArray("breakfast1" , new String[]{breakfast1[0]});
    Intent gene = new Intent(Calories.this, Days.class);
    //to pass the activity in another activity

    gene.putExtras(b); // put b not gene
    startActivity(gene);


    //second.java bundle receiving code block
    break1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.break1);
    Intent gene = getIntent();
    String[] break2 = gene.getStringArrayExtra("breakfast1");

    break1.setText(break2[0]);
```

Comment: it still crashes bro :(

Comment: yes right side checkbox just checked it thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  b.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
  Intent i = new Intent(context, Class);
  i.putExtras(b);
```

**And for receiving side**

```
 Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 String[] array = b.getStringArray(key);
```